# Does ctype.h still require unsigned char?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, c11, ctype

Traditionally, it was - strictly speaking - an error to pass a `signed char` to the `ctype.h` predicates because they were only defined for -1 to 255, so -128 to -2 could end up in reading outside array bounds.

Was this ever fixed, or do you still strictly speaking have to use `unsigned char` to avoid undefined behaviour in modern versions of C?

Comment: Modern programs have only increasing chances to be confronted to characters in the range 128-255, which would be misinterpreted as negative if seen as signed chars, so the answer is “more than ever”.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> do you still strictly speaking have to use unsigned char to avoid undefined behavior in modern versions of C?

Yes, from the [C11 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) section `7.4` *Character handling <ctype.h>* paragraph *1* says (*emphasis mine*):

> The header  declares several functions useful for classifying and mapping
>   characters.<sup>198)</sup> In all cases the argument is an int, the value of which **shall be
>   representable as an unsigned char or shall equal the value of the macro EOF**. If the
>   argument has **any other value, the behavior is undefined**.

This also holds for [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) as well, you can find it in the same section.